# Getting an error "The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first."?

Tags: android, layout, view

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Call removeView() on the child’s parent first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6526874/call-removeview-on-the-childs-parent-first)

My activity consist of 3 Listview inside 3 corresponding linear layouts.I am getting the "The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first." error in it,when I try to toggle among the listview.It is working fine when I go one by other.Kindly help me with a snippet or example to fix on this.Thank you.

My error log is

```
12-14 15:32:50.017: E/AndroidRuntime(5102): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
12-14 15:32:50.017: E/AndroidRuntime(5102):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:1976)
12-14 15:32:50.017: E/AndroidRuntime(5102):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1871)
12-14 15:32:50.017: E/AndroidRuntime(5102):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1828)
12-14 15:32:50.017: E/AndroidRuntime(5102):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1808)
12-14 15:32:50.017: E/AndroidRuntime(5102):     at com.kk.World.TheWorld.getView(TheWorld.java:629)
12-14 15:32:50.017: E/AndroidRuntime(5102):     at com.kk.World.TheWorld.onClick(TheWorld.java:428)
12-14 15:32:50.017: E/AndroidRuntime(5102):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)
12-14 15:32:50.017: E/AndroidRuntime(5102):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152)
12-14 15:32:50.017: E/AndroidRuntime(5102):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-14 15:32:50.017: E/AndroidRuntime(5102):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-14 15:32:50.017: E/AndroidRuntime(5102):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-14 15:32:50.017: E/AndroidRuntime(5102):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
12-14 15:32:50.017: E/AndroidRuntime(5102):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-14 15:32:50.017: E/AndroidRuntime(5102):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-14 15:32:50.017: E/AndroidRuntime(5102):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
12-14 15:32:50.017: E/AndroidRuntime(5102):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
12-14 15:32:50.017: E/AndroidRuntime(5102):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My view is

```
    <ListView
        android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/statelayoutStg"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/state_ll"
    android:background="@drawable/mesh"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="invisible" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/citylayoutStg"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/city_ll"
    android:background="@drawable/mesh"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="invisible" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do.  Please explain better and show your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think its possible for you to have three listviews with same id `@id/android:list` for a single `ListActivity`. And that should be the reason exactly.

If you need to use 3 ListViews then I would suggest you to extend Activity and use Custom Adapters. Since you use same ids it raises the conflict.

But still from my experience having multiple ListView in a same screen is not a good way to design UI.

Comment: Thanks @Andro I dont try to load all the three at the same time only one will be available as per selection either City,State or Country..

Comment: its good then. So first thing is you should try to use Custom adapters or use one ListView and based on user selection set the adapter and the data to it.

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 listviews with the same `android:id` you cannot do this.

```
<ListView
    android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" />
```

Without seeing your inflate getView method I can only guess that it will try to add the first instance of `ListView` when the view inflates.

Change the id's to something like
`@+id/list_view_1` `@+id/list_view_2` `@+id/list_view_3`

This should fix the issue.

Also if you are using `ListViewActivity` or `ListViewFragment` you will have to use the default class and `getViewById()` as you would any other view.