# App android crashes when i click button in second time

Tags: java, android

I am coding to make a application to manage account and password, everything 
is good, only Button Edit has problem. I click it one time, it works normaly, when i click it in second time, it crash. Can you help me?
[This is logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrF9L.png)

```
private ListView listview_account;
private Button add_new;
private EditText newtype, oldtype;
private EditText newusername, oldusername;
private EditText newpassword, oldpassword;
private List<Account> list_accounts;
private String[] list_type;
private MyDatabaseHelper helper = new MyDatabaseHelper(this);
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show);
    listview_account = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_account);
    add_new = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ADD);

    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    final View dialogView_addnew = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_addnew, null);
    final View dialogView_change = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_change, null);

    newtype = (EditText)dialogView_addnew.findViewById(R.id.type);
    newusername = (EditText)dialogView_addnew.findViewById(R.id.username);
    newpassword = (EditText)dialogView_addnew.findViewById(R.id.password);

    oldtype = (EditText)dialogView_change.findViewById(R.id.type_old);
    oldusername = (EditText)dialogView_change.findViewById(R.id.username_old);
    oldpassword = (EditText)dialogView_change.findViewById(R.id.password_old);

    update_show();

    final AlertDialog.Builder builder_show = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder_add = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder_delete = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder_change = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    builder_add.setView(dialogView_addnew);
    builder_change.setView(dialogView_change);

    builder_delete.setTitle("Delete Account");
    builder_delete.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_delete);
    builder_delete.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        }
    });

    builder_change.setTitle("Edit");
    builder_change.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_input_get);
    builder_change.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
    });

    builder_add.setTitle("Add new account");
    builder_add.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_input_add);
    builder_add.setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    try {
                        add_new_account();
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ex.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }
            }
    );
    builder_add.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    newtype.setText("");
                    newusername.setText("");
                    newpassword.setText("");
                    newtype.requestFocus();
                }
            }
    );
    final AlertDialog alert_add_new = builder_add.create();
    add_new.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
                                   @Override
                                   public void onClick(View v) {
                                       alert_add_new.show();
                                   }
                               }
    );
    listview_account.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v,final int pos, long id) {
            builder_show.setTitle(list_type[pos]);
            builder_show.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);
            builder_show.setMessage("Username: " + list_accounts.get(pos).getUSERNAME()
                    + "\nPassword: " + list_accounts.get(pos).getPASSWORD());
            builder_show.setNegativeButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            builder_delete.setMessage("Do you want to remove " + list_type[pos]+ "?\nUsername: " + list_accounts.get(pos).getUSERNAME() + "\nPassword: " + list_accounts.get(pos).getPASSWORD());

                            builder_delete.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    helper.DeleteAcc(list_type[pos]);
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    update_show();
                                }
                            });
                            final AlertDialog dialog_delete = builder_delete.create();
                            dialog_delete.show();

                        }
                    }
            );
            builder_show.setPositiveButton("Edit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            oldtype.setText(list_type[pos]);
                            oldusername.setText(list_accounts.get(pos).getUSERNAME());
                            oldpassword.setText(list_accounts.get(pos).getPASSWORD());

                            builder_change.setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    helper.DeleteAcc(list_type[pos]);
                                    change();
                                }
                            });

                            AlertDialog alert_change = builder_change.create();
                            alert_change.show();
                        }
                    }
            );
            AlertDialog alert1_show = builder_show.create();
            alert1_show.show();
        }
    });
}
private void add_new_account()
{
    String new_type = newtype.getText().toString();
    String new_username = newusername.getText().toString();
    String new_password = newpassword.getText().toString();
    Account new_acc = new Account(new_type, new_username, new_password);
    helper.AddAccount(new_acc);
    update_show();
    newtype.setText("");
    newusername.setText("");
    newpassword.setText("");
    newtype.requestFocus();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
private void change()
{
    String old_type = oldtype.getText().toString();
    String old_username = oldusername.getText().toString();
    String old_password = oldpassword.getText().toString();
    Account new_acc = new Account(old_type, old_username, old_password);
    helper.AddAccount(new_acc);
    update_show();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Đã lưu.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
private void update_show()
{
    list_accounts = helper.getListAccount();
    list_type = new String[list_accounts.size()];
    int i = 0;
    for (Account acc: list_accounts) {  list_type[i++] = acc.TYPE; }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
            (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list_type);
    listview_account.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace from the crash? You also might want to give some more info such as which button is causing the crash.

Comment: where is logcat ??

Comment: I'm sorry, this is first time I post to this site, i am editing the post.

Comment: Unrelated to question: Holy crap you have way too much code in your onCreate(). Cut and paste your OnClickListener assignments to the onStart() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for me, the problem is that you create your `builder_show` dialog inside your `ItemClickListener`.

```
listview_account.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
```

Actually, you create it every time and on second time system shows you error, that *"The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first."* Because dialog already exists.

If you wish to preserve everything as is, you should remove your dialog before every show() call. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6526874/call-removeview-on-the-childs-parent-first) for details.

**But** correct (*for this issue*) would be to move dialog creation code outside `ItemClickListener`.

Comment: You welcome :) you can also mark this answer as useful (up arrow). Thanks.